# JQuery Uncaught ReferenceError: getRadioValue is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently making an app with jQuery. I am trying to pass a value with the radio button by using localstorage and when I press Calculate, it should bring me to another html page whereby it would display the result. However, when I click on calculate, nothing has happened. When I checked for errors, I was told that in the fourth line of the first javascript, there is an uncaught reference error. I have added the codes below for convenience. Is there any solution for this? Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
     <legend>Converting</legend>
     <label for="Currency">Currency</label>
     <input type="radio" name="conversioning" id="Currency" value="Currency">

     <label for="UnitofMeasurement">Unit of Measurement</label>
     <input type="radio" name="conversioning" id="UnitofMeasurement" value="Unit of Measurement" checked>
</fieldset>

<div class="ui-block"><input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate" /></div>
```

1st Javascript:

```
(function () {
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnCalculate").bind("click", function () {
      conversioning = getRadioValue("conversioning");

      localStorage.setItem("conversioningvalue", conversioning);
      window.location = "result.html";
      });

   });

})();
```

2nd Javascript:

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

       var Conversioning = localStorage.getItem("Conversioningvalue");
      $("#lblConversioning").html(Conversioning);

   })

})();
```

Output (HTML):

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>You are currently converting<div id="lblConversioning"></div></p>
</div>
```

Comment: getRadioValue is not built-in so you need to have `function getRadioValue()` somewhere

Comment: `getRadioValue is not defined` mean `getRadioValue is not defined` !

Comment: Also why the IIFEs? And .bind is replaced by .on This will also run `$(function () { $("#btnCalculate").on("click", function () {
      conversioning = getRadioValue("conversioning");

      localStorage.setItem("conversioningvalue", conversioning);
      window.location = "result.html";
   });   });` assuming you add your missing getRadioValue function, OUTSIDE the $(function()

Comment: It looks like you just would need: `conversioning = $("[name=conversioning]:checked").val();`

Comment: @A.Wolff hello! Thank you for your help! It is now working :) Have a good day!